# How to add special-character plugin with @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

I was trying to add a basic [classic editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html) by using @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic. But as soon as I added a special character plugin it started throwing an error "CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules".

Here is the documentation link that I follow - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/special-characters.html

I don't know why the editor's doc didn't mention the way to import ClassicEditor for the special character plugin.

app.js

```js
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { SpecialCharacters } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-special-characters'; // this line making the issue.

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#about_me' ), {
    plugins: [
        'Essentials', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'List',
        // 'SpecialCharacters'
    ],
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'undo', 'redo',
            '|', 'bold', 'italic',
            '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList',
            // '|', 'specialCharacters'
        ],
    }    
} )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
})
.catch( err => {
    console.error( err.stack );
});
```